# How to add categories/sub categories in Magento using MySql

Tags: mysql, magento, addition, categories

I want to add categories and their sub categories in Magento using MySql. I am not that much aware of EAV architecture. So far I have found that catalog_category_entity is the table that describes which category is parent to whom, and its level and position etc. But I am confused on which table to add categories , as I am sure there will be multiple tables in which I need to insert data to make it work.

Need guidance on how to add categories and their subcategories and assign products to them.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.magereverse.com/ will help you out, although I would advise using the Magento category API if possible, instead of hard MySQL.

Comment: There are import/export modules built to do exactly this. Go over to the MagentoCommerce.com website and search Magento Connect. If you don't understand Magento's EAV architecture, then SQL is not for you on doing this complex job. It usually involves a complex series of joins as columns in a relational DB table become rows with attributes in EAV.